# htaccess rewrite url with query string and variables

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following files in my website

```
{website}/restserver/user-create.php?id=...
{website}/restserver/user-read.php
{website}/restserver/session-login.php
...
```

I'd like to access them using the following addresses

```
{website}/user/create?id=...
{website}/user/read?id=...
{website}/session/login?id=...
```

I think you get it. I need to use the two level path to build the filename, maintaining the querystring.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?((?!restserver/)[^/]+)/([^/])/?$ restserver/$1-$2.php [L,NC]
```

Query string will be automatically carried over to target URI.

Comment: Hi, can you explain the last line? Because I like this solution better, but I can't seem to make it work, while the one of @RamRaider does.

Comment: `^/user` and `^/session` will only work from httpd config NOT from .htaccess. Also it is not a good idea to hardcode these paths. If you need `/user/info` tomorrow then you will need another rule using that approach.

Comment: I had minor issue with my rule which is fixed now. `(?!restserver/)` is a negative lookahead that says if URI doesn't start with `restserver` then route it to `/restserver/<capture1>-<capture2>` where `capture1` and `capture2` are the captured groups `(...)` in pattern.

Comment: Thanks, now it is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/user/create$ /restserver/user-create.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/user/read$ /restserver/user-read.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/session/login$ /restserver/session-login.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the solutions above, I found a general solution.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ restserver/$1-$2.php [L]
```

Thank you all!